# Android webView smooth scroll whole page

Tags: android, webview

i am making a website app and i want to scroll whole page so i do somethng like this

```
 final Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
                repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                    if (theWebView.getContentHeight() - i > 0) 
                                        theWebView.scrollBy(0, 1);
                                        i++;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 0, 10);
```

and i want to be able to scroll half of the page also. however code above does not work it scrolls only 1/3 of my page for some reason. what am i doing wrong is there another way around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theWebView.getContentHeight()*theWebView.getScale();` (even thou getScale is deprecated)